# Control speed(viscosity) of scrolling in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, scroll, android-browser, mobile-browser

Is there any way to control the speed or in other word, the viscosity of scrolling by the user in a scrollable element in a mobile browser?

I'm focusing on android browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, scroll speed is controlled by the browser (and usually directly by the settings on the computer/device). I think your code wouldn't effect that.

**In regards to a work around...**

1. There are ways you could try to fake a different scroll speed by
   moving your own content instead of the page, however, it's a bad
   idea in terms of usability.
2. If the interest is that users have to scroll multiple times to get
   to content further down the page, I would also suggest anchor points
   with a [smooth scroll](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) option built into it. That way the control
   to jump to that content faster is left to the user.
3. And lastly, if you're concerned about users leaving your content too
   quickly and missing important information, it may be a better idea
   to better style your content to visually catch their attention
   before they begin scrolling away from it.

I hope this information helps you moving forward.